# Pass a Python + Flask variable in an HTML attribute

Tags: python, flask

(Novice btw) I'm using Python + Flask

I have Python variable I want to place in as a substitute for a `value=" "`

My attempt: `value="{{ variable }}"` didn't work

```
<form>
  <textarea value="{{ result }}"></textarea>
</form>
```

```
render_template("home.html", result=result)
```

***Any guidance appreciated.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `<textarea>{{ result }}</textarea>` instead of `<textarea value="{{ result }}"></textarea>`

Answer (score 2):

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp

textarea has only four attributes "id=", "name=", "rows=", "cols="

So, If you want to put python variable in html using *jinja*. Use,

```
<textarea>{{ result }}</textarea>
```

or

```
<textarea "id=", "name=", "rows=", "cols=">{{ result }}</textarea>
```